# directive 2004/38/ ec family members

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, france, algerian-citizens

I am from Algeria and my wife is from Spain. We will be travelling from Algeria to Russia  but we will have transit 10hours in paris, and during this time we want discover the city.
As an EU family member travelling with my wife I don’t need a visa , under directive 2004/38/ec can we go out normally without problems?

Comment: In theory you can, but it will go much more smoothly if you get a visa beforehand.  The visa is free.

Comment: I tried and i dont get it

Comment: Well that is a different question.  Did you specify that the application was for a family member (i.e., that the 2004/38/EC apply)?  What reason did they give for the refusal?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify.  Putting on hold.